# iOS: How to get Currentlocation information with GPRS not from GPS?

Tags: ios7, core-location, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I am implementing a GeoFence related functionality where the app notifies when user enter / exit into certain location. Here my problem is, when I am using Location manager services it is taking using battery. Can anyone suggest me on how to get the current location updates using GPRS.

Or suggest me a better way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `desiredAccuracy` to 3000 and you can get a location using WiFi or cell tower triangulation only. That will reduce battery usage significantly by turning off the GPS.